# How to solve this linear algebra problem(Space of diagonal matrices)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

We have space M of 3x3 matrices. Our scalar product is defined as
  = tr(AB^t)

a) We have vector sub space D of diagonal matrices. Find base and dimension of orthogonal complement of D.

Any hint would be welcome :) Thanks

Comment: **Hint:** This scalar product is exactly the dot product if we pretended that our matrices were just vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The space of $3\times 3$-matrices has dimension $9$. $D$ has dimension 3 so its orthogonal has dimension 6.

The orthogonal of $D$ are the matrices whose diagonal entries are zero.

Comment: Thanks, for brief and very usefull explanation :)

Comment: It remains to prove that it is the **orthogonal** complement, but it is almost evident...